# Justice League 'Official Trailer' vs 'Heroes Trailer'

Tags: effects, dc-extended-universe, trailers, justice-league

[image]

In the later Heroes Trailer for *Justice League* the color and settings are different from the first released Official Trailer. Why is it like that?

Are official trailers of movies released without CGI effects or any other effects added? And why?

Justice League 'Official Trailer':

Heroes Trailer:

Comment: Maybe Joss Whedon did it or first trailer was under developed for VFX part.

Comment: Differences between trailers are common and are for instance due to there not having been enough time for proper SFX when creating the first vs a later one, or a movie has changed significantly. IIRC most of the first Rogue One trailer isn't even in the movie, because the movie changed so significantly after it was released.

Comment: Feel free to flesh that out into a proper answer, maybe even with some references to this specific case.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Why didn't they wait for the Proper SFX ?

Comment: @irsha Because good marketing requires good timing. Waiting for things to be finished means they could miss key advertising opportunities. The point of trailers is to build hype and excitement. The first full trailer was released at Comic-Con, which is a massive opportunity for studios to show off movies coming down the pipe. Fans at those events usually just want to see stuff in motion, so as long as things look "good enough" that's all that really matters.